# How to add new object instances to std::list without 'new'

Tags: c++, list, object, memory-management, instantiation

Having read literally dozens of answers here on the topic of lists, vectors, the `new` operator, RAII and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new) very good description of memory allocation, I still cannot imagine a practical implementation that meets the following need. Note I am most experienced in .net and its memory management, if that helps guide any answers.

Basically, I have class (say `class RecordFile {}`) that encapsulates a text file in a particular format. Each line equates to a record that I would like to add to a `std::list<Record>` owned by a `RecordList` instance, where the `class Record` captures the data from a single line in the file.

In the `RecordList` class, I have a method `RecordList::Read()` that reads the file line-by-line, creating a new `Record` instance and adding it to the list owned by the `RecordList` instance.

In this `Read()` method is a loop that iterates over the file's lines, creating the new `Record` instances. Clearly once the file is read and the `Read()` method finishes, I would like the list of records to persist in the `RecordList` object, but I cannot see how to do this without using the 'new' operator.

How is this task intended to be performed in c++ without violating what seem like fundamental rules? In .net this would be trivial and performed exactly as said without any risk to performance or memory leakage. I understand c++ is a different beast and am trying to get to grips with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `list` container takes care of memory management for you.

Simply create a `list` member on your `RecordList` class like this:

```
std::list<Record> records_;
```

Then simply add lines using `emplace_back`:

```
records_.emplace_back(<whatever parameters `Record` constructor takes>);
```

When `RecordList` is destroyed, so is the `list` and all its elements.

Comment: That is quite cool, so elements are tightly owned by their container. Is that the entire intent for the emplace_* methods? Would this work the same way for a list where all elements belong to the same family of classes rather than just one concrete type?

Comment: @JCollins The purpose of the emplace methods is to construct the object on site,  as opposed to construct it somewhere else and then copy it into the container. And no, it wouldn't work on a family of objects, for that you would need smart pointers (`unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr`) which also handle lifetime for you. You can also create them and allocate memory for them without `new`, check the functions `make_unique`/`make_shared`

Comment: Thanks imreal, that looks like it is c++14, is that standard relatively universally adopted yet?

Comment: @JCollins I think `make_unique` is C++14 (but it is on gcc 4.9), `make_shared` is C++11 which is very well adopted. You can initialize `unique_ptr` using `new` quite safely anyway.